# How to pass (custom) functions to the "locals" argument of simpify?

Tags: python, sympy

I have two functions, `sqrt(x)` and `pow(x, y)`, that I want to pass to the "local" argument of sympify upon receiving "sqrt(pow(x,2))" as a string. After this, the goal is to simplify the expression from "sqrt(pow(x,2))" to "x" using simplify.

The code below outputs 'sqrt(x**2)', giving me a hint that the `pow(x, y)` function is picked up, but not further simplified for an unknown reason.

```
import sympy as sp

# Function Definitions
def pow(x, y):
   return x ** y

def sqrt(x):
   return sp.sqrt(x)

sp.symbols('x', positive=True, real=True)
input_exp = 'sqrt(pow(x, 2))'

eqn = sp.sympify(input_exp, locals={'sqrt': sqrt, 'pow': pow})
print("Simplification: ", sp.simplify(eqn))
```

The code below correctly outputs an 'x', but has a sympy expression as input. For my usecase, this needs to be a string. Replacing this sympy expression with a call to `sp.sympify(input_exp, locals={'sqrt': sqrt, 'pow': pow})` does not work either.

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import Function

# Function definitions
class pow(Function):
   @classmethod
   def eval(cls, x, y):
      return x ** y


class sqrt(Function):
   @classmethod
   def eval(cls, x):
      return sp.sqrt(x)


# Simplify the expression.
x = sp.symbols('x', positive=True, real=True)
print("Simplification: ", sp.simplify(sqrt(pow(x, 2))))
```

Any suggestion or solutions are more then welcome. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass 'x' as well as a local reference.
Here is the code :

```
import sympy as sp

# Function Definitions
def pow(x, y):
   return x ** y

def sqrt(x):
   return sp.sqrt(x)

x = sp.symbols('x', positive=True, real=True)
input_exp = 'sqrt(pow(x, 2))'


eqn = sp.sympify(input_exp, locals={'sqrt': sqrt, 'pow': pow, 'x':x})
print("Simplification: ", sp.simplify(eqn))
```

and

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import Function

# Function definitions
class pow(Function):
   @classmethod
   def eval(cls, x, y):
      return x ** y


class sqrt(Function):
   @classmethod
   def eval(cls, x):
      return sp.sqrt(x)


# Simplify the expression.
x = sp.symbols('x', positive=True, real=True)
input_exp = 'sqrt(pow(x, 2))'
eqn = sp.sympify(input_exp, locals={'sqrt': sqrt, 'pow': pow, 'x':x})
print("Simplification: ", sp.simplify(eqn))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The issue with this implementation is that it requires all symbols in the expression to be identified as a symbol manually, while simpify does this automatically for you. If I received an input string that does not match this pattern, it should not raise an error because of an unidentified symbol. Sorry to not make that clear. I'll update my answer!

Comment: **@QuintenRosseel** Thanks for the callback, I fixed it, if you find it working, please don't forget to vote up the answer :)

Comment: That works, thank you! I have not yet enough reputation to upvote the answer.